# How to create a content file and navigate into it from a console application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, console-application

Im working on a "text only" game with console application. I searched for ways to add sound to my application, but all of the solutions needed to include a path to the .wav file location. that would work, but I want to publish my game later on. and the file location matches only my PC, I mean, the user who downloads it can put the content file in a diffrent location than c:/Mygame/Content. what if he has multiple hard-drives? or a Disk on key? the program wont play the sound, because it cant find the sound. any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried a relative path instead?  Place your sound file in the bin directory and then just the file name 'foo.wav'

Answer (score 2):

Store the WAV file in a location relative to your .exe file and use:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
```

to dynamically get the location of your .exe file at runtime and append it to the name of the .WAV file.

Comment: After i got the location of the .exe file, i had two problems; 1. it runs the .exe file, (ofcurse it is. but how do i fix it? 2- its kind of messed up,  have many sounds end the game itself is getting lost. can i put the content near it inside a foldr somhow?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it myself with these lines of code:
` string exe_location = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
            exe_location = exe_location.Remove(exe_location.Length - 11);
            int last_path_chat = exe_location.Length;

```
        string sound_location = exe_location.Insert(last_path_chat, "DIE_ANTWOORD_-_UGLY_BOY.wav");
```

`SoundPlayer.SoundLocation = sound_location;
            SoundPlayer.PlaySync();`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to have your console application reference the .wav format file through a relative path(something like "~/Content", and have it called in reference to the current directory of the application. Once that's done, you could build a simple installer(or just have the .wav file site in the program directory if you'll just be deploying your app via copy) to deploy your app.

I'm at work right now so can't do any quick testing, but if this question is still outstanding when I get home tonight I'll mock something up and post it here.

Comment: should i do somthing like this? `SoundPlayer.SoundLocation = @"~\kth;tls_content_orig\DIE_ANTWOORD_-_UGLY_BOY.wav";`

Comment: You might be able to actually leave the ~ off and just use @"kth;tls_content_orig\DIE_ANTWOORD_-_UGLY_BOY.wav"; LIke I said, I'll have to test when I get home. Also see A Wabbi's answer above, as that may also prove useful if you end up needing to base your path off the current working directory of the program(certain deployment schemes can cause this necessity).

Comment: Yes! sorry, I got home and we had a small family emergency. working on it now. I'll get something posted soon.
EDIT:
I see you got it solved. Awesome!